# How can a viral infection (like shingles) recur in a healthy individual?

Tags: virology

I don't quite understand how a viral infection, like chicken pox (Herpes Zoster), can recur in a healthy individual. If the body has created an immune response, how can the virus just spontaneously reactivate in a healthy adult? Or is this just an unknown mystery?

I understand that in an older person, perhaps the immune system weakens, so there is a recurrence, but shingles does recur in ordinary adults. For example, apparently Justin Bieber has had shingles and he is 28 years old.

Comment: What have you learned from reading about shingles?

Comment: I once saw a 6 year old immunocompetent child with shingles. Herpesviruses are very interesting viruses. The herpesvirus responsible for infectious mononucleosis reactivates often and asymptomaticly. It makes for some interesting reading.

Comment: When I got shingles for the second time at the age of 28, a colleague who studies such things laid out a hypothesis that shingles (zoster) has gotten more among common younger adults, in part, because of more widespread use of the chickenpox vaccine. In a nutshell, the body's adaptive immune responses wane over time. Occasional re-exposure to similar antigens can help boost that response and help maintain it for longer. Now that most kids are vaccinated and never get chickenpox, there's a lot less natural re-exposure happening for those of us who were taken to chickenpox parties as kids.